# How do you sort a string within a class parameter?

Tags: c++, string, class, sorting, bubble-sort

My professor has asked us to make a program that will take a user's input and continue reading until the end of input. Only then, can the program output what the user has typed.

Input should be based on video title, it's url, comments made on the video, length (in minutes), and rating (in *).

For example:

> United Break Guitars, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v+5YGc4zOqozo, Great example of one person getting a giant company to listen, 4.5, ***, Space Versus Tabs, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsoOG6ZeyUl, Decide for yourself: spaces or tabs?, 2.83, ****

Before inputting any video description, the user needs to specify a sorting method of three choices, `Rating, Length, or title`. I have completed most of the code and sort method asked by my professor (bubble sort), however when I ask the program to sort by title (which is the only one of the three options that is a string), it does not output correctly.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

#include "video.h"


int main()
{
    string user, url, comment, title;
    int rating;
    double length;
    int i = 0, last = 0;

    Video *videoObj[100];


   // specifies how the videos should be sorted
   cin >> user;
   cin.ignore();


while (getline(cin,title)  ) {


    getline(cin, url);
    getline(cin, comment);
    cin >> length;
    cin >> rating;
    cin.ignore();



    videoObj[i] = new Video(title, url, comment, length, rating);
    i++;
    last++;
    }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------- Sorts the list based on rating (*) ---------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if(user=="rating"){

        for(int i = 0; i < last - 1; i++){

    for(int j = 0; j< last - i -1; j++){

    if(videoObj[j +1]->Rating(videoObj[j])){
            swap(videoObj[j], videoObj[j+1]);

      }
    }
  }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------- Sorts the list based on length -------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if(user=="length"){

        for(int i = 0; i < last - 1; i++){

    for(int j = 0; j< last - i -1; j++){

    if(videoObj[j +1]->Length(videoObj[j])){
            swap(videoObj[j], videoObj[j+1]);


      }
    }
  }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------- Sorts the list based on title --------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

 if(user=="title"){

        for(int i = 0; i < last - 1; i++){

    for(int j = 0; j< last - i -1; j++){

    if(videoObj[j +1]->Title(videoObj[j])){
            swap(videoObj[j], videoObj[j+1]);

      }
    }
  }
}


   for(int i= 0; i < last; i++){

    videoObj[i]->print();

   }

     //delete[] videoObj;

return 0;
}
```

video.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#include "video.h"

Video::Video(string video_title, string video_link, string video_comment, double video_length, int video_number)
: title(video_title), link(video_link), comment(video_comment), length(video_length), rating(video_number)
{
 m_title = title;
 m_link = link;
 m_comment = comment;
 m_length = length;
 m_rating = rating;
}


bool Video::Rating(Video *other)
{
    if(m_rating > other-> m_rating){
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


bool Video::Length(Video *other2)
{
     if(m_length > other2-> m_length){
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool Video::Title(Video *other3)
{
     if(m_length > other3-> m_length){
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void Video::print(){

string star;
switch(rating){

case 1:
    star = "*";
    break;
case 2:
    star = "**";
    break;
case 3:
    star = "***";
    break;
case 4:
    star = "****";
    break;
case 5:
    star = "*****";
    break;

}

 cout << title << ", " << link << ", " << comment << ", " << length << ", " << star << endl;

}
```

video.h:

```
#ifndef VIDEO_H
#define VIDEO_H

using namespace std;

class Video {

public:
    Video(string video_title, string video_link, string video_comment, double video_length, int video_number);
    void print();
    bool Rating(Video *other);
    bool Length(Video *other2);
    bool Title(Video *other3);




private:


    string m_title;
    string m_link;
    string m_comment;
    double m_length;
    int m_rating;

    string title;
    string link;
    string comment;
    double length;
    int rating;

};


#endif
```

I'm not exactly sure what I need to do to `title` to make it function correctly. I was thinking of comparing by strings, but again, not sure where to start.

Also, another question, how do I use `delete[] videoObj;`without getting an error?

Comment: Why use one of the worst sorts known in computer science (the bubble sort)?  Just use `std::sort` with a predicate function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie haha yeah, that's just what he recommended. I'm not exactly sure how and where I would start with std::sort. All of this is new to me

Comment: Your `Video` class has no way from the outside world to get to any of the data, since the data is all `private`.  So it is basically a useless class to `main` or any other function or class outside of `Video`.  You should first create a `Video` class where the data can be queried and also set.  Right now, all you have is a constructor and a print statement.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But it works though..? What would you recommend I do?

Comment: How does it work if for example, `main` wants to get the title of a `Video` object?  Where is the `Video::getTitle()` or similar function?

Comment: "it does not output correctly" -- that's an interpretation, which is secondary to a good question. The primary info is the actual output and what you would expect instead. BTW, you should also provide a [mcve], which includes hardcoding the inputs in your case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is wrong, just a typo probably

```
bool Video::Title(Video *other3)
{
     if(m_length > other3-> m_length){
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It should be `m_title` not `m_length` (probably)

```
bool Video::Title(Video *other3)
{
     if(m_title > other3-> m_title){
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also this code can be simplified, the above can be written in one line

```
bool Video::Title(Video *other3)
{
    return m_title > other3-> m_title;
}
```

`if (xxx) return true; else return false;` is exactly the same as `return xxx;`. Beginners often don't realise you can *calculate* with booleans in this is way.

Comment: To go further, `const` can be added to both method and pointer, and pointer should probably be reference.